# Interfacing arduino with LabVIEW

Tags: labview

I have already downloaded the arduino package for LabVIEW, MakerHub LINX, NI-Visa, and I've uploaded LIFA_Base to arduino, and it still does not work :(.
My questions are:

1) Do I need to upload the LIFA_Base to arduino every time I want to interface arduino with LabVIEW, or is once enough? (the order I'm following is: upload LIFA_Base -> upload my arduino code -> run the LabVIEW code)

2) I know my arduino UNO is receiving info by the LabVIEW software because the RX led goes on every time I press the ON/OFF buttons, what could be the problem?

The ideia of this humble project is to turn on/off LED through the LabVIEW. The arduino code follows the LebVIEW code.
[image]

```
String c, string;
int led = 2;

void setup() {
   Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
   if (Serial.available() > 0) string = "";

   while(Serial.available() > 0)
   {
     c = (byte)Serial.read();
       if (c == ":")
       {
         break;
       }else
       {
         string += c;
       }
     delay(1);
   }

   if (string == "LL")
   {
     digitalWrite(led, HIGH);
   }
   if (string == "DL")
   {
     digitalWrite(led, LOW);
   } 
}
```

Comment: Long time LabVIEW and Arduino user, but never used LIFA.  I did a quick look at the [getting started](http://vishots.com/getting-started-with-the-labview-interface-for-arduino/) for LIFA. If I'm not mistaken, do you even need to upload your own Arduino code? Doesn't the LIFA_Base.pde take care of the interpretation of these serial commands for you, or am I totally missing something?

Comment: I have just started to combine arduino with LabVIEW, so I have no  experience to tell if you are actually missing something. How did you use to work with arduino and LabVIEW? Because I think I am mixing up different ways to do the same thing and that's why it's not working. Did you use the arduino elements from LabVIEW or just the VISA ones? Thanks!!

Comment: I've personally always just used VISA elements, and then wrote Arduino code similar to like what you have above.  But the LIFA elements look like they would be easier to get started with! And for that I'm pretty sure you just want to upload LIFA_Base.pde to the arduino.

Comment: From the LabVIEW side of things, I would just go with an event structure and use a single boolean to control the LED - let it go idle when the button state has not changed. No need to poll!

Comment: “_upload LIFA_Base -> upload my arduino code_”. You can only have one program in the Arduino at a time. When you upload your Arduino code, you are overwriting the previously uploaded LIFA_Base.